# Adapting psalm output to Neomake

Tags: php, neovim, errorformat, neomake, psalm-php

I'm trying to come up with the correct errorformat to pass to Neomake, for handling output from psalm (https://github.com/vimeo/psalm).

Example output:

```
|| ERROR: UndefinedClass - application/libraries/PluginManager/PluginBase.php:58:13 - Class or interface LimeSurvey\PluginManager\XML does not exist
```

(The double bars are only visible in the `:lopen` list, not in the console. Not sure why.)

Errorformat I've tried:

```
||\ ERROR:\ %m\ -\ %f:%l:%c
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Grateful for any tips or links or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
'errorformat': '%tRROR:\ %s\ \\-\ %f:%l:%c\ \\-\ %m,%tNFO:\ %s\ \\-\ %f:%l:%c\ \\-\ %m',
```

Comment: Psalm now has `--output-format` with the following options: `compact`, `console`, `emacs`,`json`,`pylint`,`xml`,`checkstyle` and `sonarqube`. `pylint` is probably most useful in linting context.